# Load semantic-ui dropdown with remote data

Tags: jquery, json, semantic-ui

I have been reading through the semantic ui remote content documentation for dropdowns ([here](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#remote-content)) but can't seem to figure out how to use it in my case.

I have a function that queries back4app (parse) for the required data and converts it to JSON. How do I populate the returned data into the dropdown? Do I have to build it manually or can I pass the JSON directly somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using ResponseAsync - see code excerpt below. It works for me. The issue is that I am not using a URL with parse to run the query - sorry, I missed to say this.

```
$('.ui.dropdown.age_group').dropdown({
    onChange: function(value, text, $choice){
        $('.ui.dropdown.group').dropdown('clear');
      GetGroups();
    ;
    },
    apiSettings: {
        responseAsync: function(settings, callback) {

    var query = new Parse.Query("Teams");
      query.ascending("AGE_GROUP");
    query.find({
     success: function(results) {
         var jsonArray = [];

     // Create the JSON array that the dropdown needs
        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
           jsonArray.push(results[i].toJSON());
        }

    // Create the required json for the dropdown (needs name and value)
        var myresults = jsonArray.map(function(item) {
            return {
                name: item,
                value: item
            }
        });

        var response = {
            success: true,
            results: myresults
          };
      // This will populate the dropdown
          callback(response);
        },
        error: function(error) {

      }
    });
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

In your dropdown initialization, add an apiSettings hash for remote data:

```
   $(selector)
   .dropdown({
      apiSettings: {
            url: <Your_API_URL>,
            beforeXHR: (xhr) => {
               // Set Custom Headers here 
              xhr.setRequestHeader(key, val)
            },
            onResponse: (response) => {
              // Modify your JSON response into the format SUI wants
              return response
            }
});
```

[This](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#remote-content) is the response format Semantic-UI expects

For your use case, you might have to break down your function into two parts:
 1. The part that fetches the data
 2. The part that sanitizes the data into JSON

You'll have to use the apiSettings hash to fetch data for you (just put in your URL and custom headers such as authentication). This would replace part 1 of your function.

When the data is returned, SUI's onResponse() method is called. Call your function that sanitizes the data into JSON here.

You might have to modify the JSON response slightly to conform to how SUI expects it.

Comment: thanks. See my answer - I hope that is the correct method. Let me know if you think of anything better.